# Combine git repos preserving history by tag

Tags: git, git-merge

I have several separated Git repositories - the "core" and several components. Each of them has a tag like "v1.0.1" indicating that it was included in the build. The tag is the same among all repos. Now I need to combine these repos into single repo preserving history by tag. The purpose of this is that I need to be able to build historical releases (based on tag). Files in repos don't conflict (except .gitignore).

I tried `git reset v1.0.1` on "core" followed by merge with corresponding tag on other repos (added as remotes in core) `git merge comp1/master v1.0.1` but it merges all commits from `comp1/master` branch. Is it possible to do git merge with commit that is not source's HEAD? Maybe there is an alternate approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It merge all in master because you point to to `comp1/master`, just point it to the tag you want to merge.

Here I'm telling you to point to the tag, although, I guess every tag have the same name on every repo - so this won't work as tag name must be unique.

So, what you'll want to do, is starting with a `fetch` from a component repo (`git fetch componentARemote` (you may need to select the branch to fetch).

Once this is done, you'll have merge every commit from the component remote in your git repo. Then, you can just check what is the commit `sha` pointed by tag `v1.0.1` no the component branch. And then, you merge it by pointing it's sha:

```
git checkout v1.0.1 # this is your core tag
git merge <sha id>
# and here you are, you merged only the relevant component tag
```